# how create JSON file with variable of type String

Tags: java, android, json

i have a variable of type `String` and i need create a json file with this variable.

I need to create `JSON file` with content of variable `"result"`.

I hope that you can help me!

Thanks in advance!

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public String showResult(View v) throws IOException {

        String  result = "";

        Gson json = new Gson();
        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()){
                /*json.put("name",p.getName());
                json.put("distance",p.getDistance());
                json.put("quantity",p.getQuantità());*/
                result=result+json.toJson(p);


            }
        }
         //result=json.toString();

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText/";

        //FileWriter file=null;

    /*  try {
            file = new FileWriter(path+"filename5.json");
            file.write(result);


        }catch(IOException ie){}
        finally{


            file.flush();
            file.close();
        }*/try(FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path + "filename.json"))  {
        //  file=new FileWriter(path+"filename100.json");
        /*FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path+"filename31.json");
            file.write(result);
        file.close();
        */
            json.toJson(result);
            //System.out.println("Successfully wrote Json result to file.");
        /*catch(IOException r){

        }*/
        }catch (IOException e){

        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: create JSONObject using all values

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String showResult(View v) {
        String  result = "";
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject():
         for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
                    if (p.isSelected()){
                       json.put("name",p.getName());
                       json.put("distance",p.getDistance());
                       json.put("quantity",p.getQuantità());
                    }
           }
         result = json.toString();
         FileWriter file = null;
         try { 
                file = new FileWriter("/path/filename.json");
                file.write(result); 
         }catch(IOException ie){}
         finally{ 
           file.flush();
           file.close();
         }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: he needs to create a json file not JSon object

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @rajanks with your example i store on smartphone file JSON? i need to store it

Comment: can i get a screeshot?

Comment: @rajanks can you help me please? I added screenshot under your code

Comment: @rajanks when i open json file on my smartphone, i don't see content of my variable "result"....

Comment: @rajanks my method must return a String?

Comment: you want to save it in file and return the String ?

Comment: I want save in a file but with this code, file is not contain json file

Comment: @rajanks if i open file in my smartphone i have the name of the package of my app

Answer (score 1):

A little modification to the same answer above by @rajan-ks. This one uses `try-with-resource` statement to declare a `FileWriter` instance. You don't need to close the `FileWriter` instance and also no need to catch the `IOException` as it is suppressed (as per [Java Language Specification 14.20.3])

**Update 1:** Updated `showResult()` to work with gson.

```
public static String showResult(View v) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    Gson json = new Gson();

    for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.isSelected()) {
            result = result + json.toJson(p);
        }
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText/";

    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path + "filename.json")) {
        json.toJson(result, file);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: when i click on JSON file to open it with JSON viewer on my smartphone, the file is all white...

Comment: @ZAO: Which JSON framework you're using, as this works at my end? I'm using Google Gson, though not on Android.

Comment: with json viewer(app for Android) it doesn't work....you can try with my same app and you can see that it doesn't work

Comment: No, what I meant was which gradle dependency provides you with `JsonObject` (Jackson, or Gson, or JSON.simple, or something else)? Also, can you share the exact `showResult` method that you're using?

Comment: my grade dependency is  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/tinydb-0.0.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')...now i edited code so you can see my method complete

Comment: @ZAO: Hmm. I don't see a Json dependency in your gradle. Have you created your own `JsonObject` class? Also, somewhere before `FileWriter` add this line and check what it prints in your logs: `Log.i("Json value: " + json.toString())`

Let us know what is logged

Comment: Also, I'd suggest to close the `FileWriter` object if you're not using `try-with-resource` statement. `file.close()`

Comment: with file.close Now i see the name of package of my app and i don t see json file correct

Comment: Can you post/screenshot your `JsonObject` class?

Comment: Private static class JaonObjectClass{ public void put (String name, String name1){}}

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a Json library like `JSONObject` (https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) in lieu of the `JsonObject` class you gave above. It contains the `put` and `toString()` implementations that you require here.

Comment: i imported gson-2.2.2.jar and Now?

Comment: @ZAO: I updated my answer with the new code for gson. it should work. Btw, make sure that your `showResult` method `throws IOException` like in the first line: `public static String showResult(View v) throws IOException`

Comment: in consolle i see json file while if i open file json with app on smartphone, file is white....is empty....why?

Comment: Are you sure there is not a `finally` block in your code? And that `FileWriter` is not being instantiated before the `try` statement?

Comment: on this line:"(FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path + "filename.json")) " IDE say me API 19 (current min is 15)